# Catch That Image

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the catch_that_image function working well for my OG tags in my functions.php
Right now I am trying to output the image link in the loop using

```
<?php echo catch_that_image(); ?>
```

Currently it works only to output my backup image even if I have images available. How do I get it working to output first image like how I did for my OG tags?

For my OG tags, n my functions.php, before the echo catch_that_image();  there is

```
function abc (){
if (is_single()) {
    global $post;
    $output = preg_match_all('/img src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"]/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
    ?>
        <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo catch_that_image(); ?>" />
```

Am I supposed to include global $post & $output elements in the echo catch_that_image code in the loop for it to output properly? How should I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that's because of `if (is_single()) {` line.

Comment: The latter block of code is working fine for OG tags. I am trying to now output <?php echo catch_that_image();?> in the Loop but its not working as it did for my OG tags.